# Regex not validating correctly in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot seem to get validation to pass in Rails 4 app using regex for email.

Subscriber.rb

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false, message: "You're already subscribed!"
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /@/i, message: "Email is invalid"
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase if email}

end
```

No matter how simple my regex is, I get the "Email is invalid" message.

Any ideas or am I doing something obviously wrong (regex isn't a strong suit for me).

Thanks!

_subscribe.html.erb

```
<%= form_for Subscriber.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "uppercase", :placeholder => "Stay in touch. Enter your email" %>
    <%= f.submit :class => "submit uppercase", :value => 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Line that calls the partial:
`<%= render :partial => 'shared/subscribe', :subscriber => Subscriber.new %>`

subscribers_controller.rb

```
include SubscribersHelper

def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
    if @subscriber.save(subscriber_params)
        redirect_to(:back)
        flash.notice = "You are now subscribed"
    else
        redirect_to(:back)
        flash.alert = "There was an error with your subscription: "
        flash.alert += @subscriber.errors.messages.values.join(", ")
    end
end
```

SubscribersHelper.rb

```
def subscriber_params
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email)
end
```

Comment: If you are including any thing that contains `@`, it wil be shown invalid, because you regex says so..try it on a string without `@`

Comment: I'd try replacing the regex with `/.*@.*/` - `validates` might be expecting the regex to match the whole string.

Comment: @rock321987 - Trying it with a string that didn't contain @ did not work

Comment: check this site :- http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: @JavaNut13 - that didn't seem to fix it either. Any other ideas or thoughts on where else this could be breaking?

Comment: @rock321987 - I've been all over that page. Even copying their example doesn't pass validation :/

Comment: That's wierd..someone with ROR background will help you

Comment: Works as expected for me in Rails 4.2. How specifically are you creating your `Subscriber`? What is `email` when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Above is a pretty failsafe email RegEx.

Comment: This may signify a deeper issue: When I use that regex using my gmail email, I get `can't be blank, is invalid`. When I remove the "presence: true," part, I only get the `is invalid` error. Looking through other stackoverflow questions, I ended up trying to create a subscriber from the console and that was successful with no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing this in a form? What are you using to create a sub?

Comment: Yes. This is a partial that will be rendered on most pages of the site. I'll post the code for all that up top